# Looking for nice ways to display Java on a webpage

Tags: java, html

Anyone have good (has to be free!) ways of displaying Java code in the browser in a nice pretty format? I've seen many examples on various websites but have no experience with using any. What are your favorites? Easy to use is a plus!

Features wanted:

- free
- easy to use with a tag (not required)
- color coded syntax

Comment: Show some work. What have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/) is my favorite.
If you want to host your own code, check [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/)
If you want a server-side one, [Java2Html](http://www.java2html.de/) could be an option (don't think it supports html tough), or I made one long time back called [jrainbow](http://code.google.com/p/jrainbow/) (development is abandoned).

Gist is easy: you paste the code on the gist website then you grab the html code to embed on your website.

SyntaxHighlighter is also simple: just include some javascript in your website, then put your code within `<pre class="brush:java"> your code here </pre>` and specify the language after `brush:`, there are many supported. You can also have line numbers and other things.

For jrainbow, checkout the code via svn, then do `mvn jetty:run` and open the browser at `http://localhost:8081/jrainbow/` to try it. I was planning to make some JSP tag to ease usage.

Comment: I tried out SyntaxHighlighter and all the Java code is Red. Any idea why this could be?

Comment: nevermind...missing an include

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the way that Oracle does it [- Syntax highlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) . Here is how it appears:

[image]

Comment: I tried Syntax Highlighter and all the java is red when displayed in the browser...any idea why this could be?

Comment: nevermind...missing an include